# Operator overloading with non-member function?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am reading [Effective c++](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Effective-Specific-Addison-Wesley-Professional-Computing/dp/0201924889) and came across this:

```
class Rational { ... };
const Rational operator*(const Rational& lhs, const Rational& rhs);
```

Is this operator overloading? If yes, why is it in weird form?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's weird about it?

Comment: @aaronman Shouldn't it be `Rational::operator` to indicate the class?

Comment: It's not just not weird, it's actually considered good style by many.

Comment: No because it's not a member, sometimes you can have operators defined outside the class itself

Comment: The only weird thing is that the return value is marked `const Rational`.  The rest is a non-member function operator overload.

Comment: Scott Meyers makes the point (either in that book or elsewhere) that it's sometimes better *not* to make things member functions. e.g. http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197

Comment: _"because I am at least of level this book requires"_ ever heard of `friend` or public member function ?

Comment: @P0W Well, I just read about those but that doesn't make any difference, does it?

Comment: I mean about `friend` ones

Answer (score 2):

> Is this operator overloading? If yes, why is it in weird form?

Yes.  The form is not "weird".  This is just one form which allows you to multiply two rational numbers together.

Operators can be overloaded as member functions or non-member functions.  The main advantage of using a non-member function (like this) is that you're making it clear that you're not accessing any private state of the `Rational` class, nor modifying the left hand operand (which is also clear due to the `const`).

The member function versions are only required if you're going to modify the left hand operand (`this`) or need access to the private variables within the types, which requires it to be part of the class.  Otherwise, access to private state would require this to be declared as a friend function.

Comment: The function can access private state if it is declared as a friend.

Comment: Thank, I will probably change the title, as it might help other too.

Answer (score 1):

It's common and a good idea. You usually implement operators in terms of other operator and you try to avoid having too many member functions. In your case:

```
class Rational
{
public:
    // member function for += with access to the internals
    Rational& operator+=( const Rational& rhs );
};

// free function for + using public copy-ctor and +=,
// therefore no need to access internals of Rational
// and hence no need to be a member or friend of Rational!
Rational operator+( const Rational& lhs, const Rational& rhs )
{
    Rational result( lhs );
    result += rhs;
    return result;
}
```

Since the second method follows a common pattern, there are libraries to help you with that, e.g. [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) or my [df.operators](https://github.com/d-frey/operators/). With the help of these libraries, you just need

```
class Rational : df::commutative_addable< Rational >
{
public:
    // member function for += with access to the internals
    Rational& operator+=( const Rational& rhs );
};
```

to have + generated for you automatically.